# Why I can't do this: ${someValue} in JavaScript / Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an issue. JavaScript do not recognize code inside curly braces:

```
let a = 'John'; let s = 'Hello ${a}'; // output: 'Hello ${a}' instead of 'Hello John'
```

I have updated Typescript to latest version: `npm install typescript@latest`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only works with backticks, not quotes.

Do `Hello ${a}` instead of 'Hello ${a}'

Answer (score 3):

You write single quotes, which doesn't have interpolation capability.

Please try "backtick" char, which will solve your issue

```
`Hello ${a}`
```

You can read more about this here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals

Answer (score 1):

whenever you want to use template string, you have to wrap up with the backtick (type `alt` + `96`), the correct syntax is:

```
`string ${YOUR_VARIABLE} string`
```

read this document:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals